# Generar contenido html de acuerdo a combobox luego de presionar un button

Tags: jquery

Tengo un formulario html con:

1 combo de curso, 1 combo de division, y 1 combo de turno

se trata de un colegio.

Si se va a tomar asistencia  a la mañana se debem listar los alumnos(ya lo tengo en un button con php) en una tabla con 5 columnas para el tipo de falta:

inasistencia, llegada tarde 40 minutos despues y 80 minutos despues, retiro anticipado 40 minutos antes y 80 minutos antes.

Pero si es de tarde solo se deben mostrar 3 columnas:

inasistencia, llegada tarde y retiro anticipado

Cuando cargo la pagina tengo los tres combos, pero de que manera puedo, al hacer click en el button, ademas de consultar el listado de alumnos, mostrar la tabla de acuerdo al combo de turno, si selecciona mañana las 5 primeras y sino las 3 ultimas.

JS:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
function nuevoAjax(){
    var xmlhttp=false;
    try {
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    } catch (e) {
        try {
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (E) {
            xmlhttp = false;
        }
    }

    if (!xmlhttp && typeof XMLHttpRequest!='undefined') {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    return xmlhttp;
}
$(document).ready(function(){

 $("#listar").click(function(){


 var url = "consultaInasistencias.php"; // El script a dónde se realizará la petición.
    $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: url,
           data: $("#busqueda").serialize(), // Adjuntar los campos del formulario enviado.
           success: function(data)
           {
               $("#respuesta").html(data); // Mostrar la respuestas del script PHP.
           }
         });

    return false; // Evitar ejecutar el submit del formulario.
 });


 $("#Actualizar").click(function(){

 var url = "insertar.php"; // El script a dónde se realizará la petición.
    $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: url,
           data: $("#listado").serialize(), // Adjuntar los campos del formulario enviado.
           success: function(data)
           {
               $("#respuesta").html(data); // Mostrar la respuestas del script PHP.
           }
         });

    return false; // Evitar ejecutar el submit del formulario.
 });
});
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html" />


    <title>Sistema de Gestion de Alumnos</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../Css/Formularios.css"/>
    <script src="../../../Sistema/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="listado.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="contenedor">

        <header id="cabecera">  
            <div id="C1">
                <div class="imagen1"><div class="imagen2"></div></div>
                <p class="icono">GESTION.AR</p>
            </div>

            <div id="box">
               <p id="titulo">Sistema de Gestión Escolar</p>
            </div>
        </header>
        <form action="" method="post" id="busqueda">
         <section id="seccion">
            <p>Seleccione el curso y la division a listar </p><br />
            <p>Curso:<select name="cursos">
             <?php foreach ( $rscursos as $curso){?>
                         <option value="<?php echo $curso["idcurso"];?>"><?php echo $curso["curso"];?></option>

                <?php }?>
          </select> Division:
           <select name="divisiones">
             <?php foreach ( $rsdivisiones as $division){?>
                         <option value="<?php echo $division["iddivision"];?>"><?php echo $division["division"];?></option>

                <?php }?>
           </select>Turno:
           <select id="turno">
           <option value="" selected="selected">Seleccione...</option>
            <option value="M">Mañana</option>
            <option value="T">Tarde</option>
           </select>
           <input type="button" id="listar" value="Obtener listado"/></p>
       <p><?php if (isset($msj)){ echo $msj;}?></p>
       </section>

    </form>
        <form method='post' id='listado' name='listado'>
         <section id='seccion'> 

            <table class='listaalumnos'>
            <tr>

                <th width='25%' id='titulocolumna' rowspan='2'>Nombre</th>

                <th width='25%' id='titulocolumna'rowspan='2'>Apellido</th>
                <th scope='col' colspan='6' width='25%' id='titulocolumna'>Inasistencia:</th>
            <tr><td width='10%' id='titulocolumna' >Entera</td>
                <td width='10%'id='titulocolumna'>Hasta 40min</td>
                <td width='10%'id='titulocolumna'>Hasta 80min</td>
                <td width='10%'id='titulocolumna'>Antes 40min</td>
                <td width='10%'id='titulocolumna'>Antes 80min</td></tr>

            </tr>

            <?php 
            if (isset($rsalumnos) && $rsalumnos!=null){
              $total=count($rsalumnos);
              $i=0;
              ?> <input type='hidden' name='total' id='total' value='<?php echo count($rsalumnos); ?>'/><?php
                foreach($rsalumnos as $alumno){$i++; ?><tr>
              <div><input type='hidden' size='0%' name='idalu<?php echo $i;?>' id='idalu' value='<?php echo $alumno['idalumno'];?>'/> 

               <td width='25%'> <?php echo $alumno['nombre'];?></td> 
               <td width='25%'> <?php echo $alumno['apellido']; ?></td> 
               <td width='10%'> <input type='radio' value='1' name='alumno<?php echo $i;?>' id='i1' /></td>
               <td width='10%'> <input type='radio' value='2' name='alumno<?php echo $i;?>' id='i2' /></td> 
               <td width='10%'> <input type='radio' value='3' name='alumno<?php echo $i;?>' id='i3'/></td>
               <td width='10%'> <input type='radio' value='4' name='alumno<?php echo $i;?>' id='i4'/></td> 
               <td width='10%'> <input type='radio' value='5' name='alumno<?php echo $i;?>' id='i5'/></td>
               </tr>
               <?php }}?>
            </div>
            </table>
       <div id='respuesta'></div>
             </section> 
        <input type="button" id="Actualizar" value="actualizar"/>

 </form>
<div id="respuesta"> 

        <footer id="pie"></footer>

    </div>
 </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ¿podrias compartir tu codigo?

Comment: @ReneLimon ahi edite la publicacion..gracias

Answer (score 1):

Bueno, logre hacer la parte de cambiar los titulos de las columnas de acuerdo al turno. Aclaro: no se si sera la mejor solucion..
Tengo dos script con el codigo html dentro de un echo

div2.php

```js
 <?php echo("
  <table class='listaalumnos'>
            <tr>
             
                <th width='25%' id='titulocolumna' rowspan='2'>Nombre</th>
             
                <th width='25%' id='titulocolumna'rowspan='2'>Apellido</th>
                <th scope='col' colspan='6' width='25%' id='titulocolumna'>Inasistencia:</th>
            <tr><td width='10%' id='titulocolumna' >Entera</td>
                <td width='10%'id='titulocolumna'>Hasta 40min despues</td>
                <td width='10%'id='titulocolumna'>Hasta 80min antes</td>
                <td width='10%'id='titulocolumna'>Hasta 40min despues</td>
                <td width='10%'id='titulocolumna'>Hasta 80min antes</td>
            
            
            </tr>
       ");?>
```

div1.php

```js
 <?php echo("
  <table class='listaalumnos'>
            <tr>
             
                <th width='25%' id='titulocolumna' rowspan='2'>Nombre</th>
             
                <th width='25%' id='titulocolumna'rowspan='2'>Apellido</th>
                <th scope='col' colspan='6' width='25%' id='titulocolumna'>Inasistencia:</th>
            <tr><td width='10%' id='titulocolumna' >Entera</td>
                <td width='10%'id='titulocolumna'>Hasta 20min despues</td>
                <td width='10%'id='titulocolumna'>Hasta 20min antes</td>
            
            
            </tr>");
            ?>
```

y este es el archivo de funciones js

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

   $('#curso').load("getcursos.php");
 $('#division').load("getdivisiones.php");

$("#turno").change(function(){
       var turno = $("#turno").val();
      
    if (turno=="M"){
    $("#divasistencia").load("/Sistema/Paginas/Preceptoria/div2.php");

    }else if (turno=="T")
    {
     $("#divasistencia").load("/Sistema/Paginas/Preceptoria/div1.php");   
        
    }  
    
});

$("#listar").click(function(){


    var url = "consultaInasistencias.php"; // El script a dónde se realizará la petición.
    $.ajax({
      
           type: "POST",
           url: url,
           data: $("#busqueda").serialize(), // Adjuntar los campos del formulario enviado.
           success: function(data)
           {
               $("#divasistencia2").html(data); // Mostrar la respuestas del script PHP.
           }
         });

});
 $("#Actualizar").click(function(){

 var url = "insertar.php"; // El script a dónde se realizará la petición.
    $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: url,
           data: $("#listado").serialize(), // Adjuntar los campos del formulario enviado.
           success: function(data)
           {
               $("#respuesta").html(data); // Mostrar la respuestas del script PHP.
           }
         });

    return false; // Evitar ejecutar el submit del formulario.
 });
});
```

por supuesto despues muestro los divs en html, pero no logro mostrar los datos de los alumnos debajo.